# vertical bar chart with with user input and validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, charts

i need a make a code where the user can add the max points, achieved points and his name. this is my code..most things are already working, i just need a function to change the max points, right now its a static number.

```
<head>
    <title>examAnalysis</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    div {
        float: left; margin-right: 10px;
    }
    div p { 
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var participant = [];
var maxPoints = 100;
var barWidth = 75;

window.onload = function() { document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = maxPoints; } function setMaxPoints() { maxPoints = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value; }        

function gatherData()
{
    var name = window.prompt('Please enter the name of the participant:');
    name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if ((/[^A-Z\s\-\']/gi.test(name)) || (name == '') || (name == 'undefined'))
    {
        alert ('You must enter a valid name! ');
        return;
    }

    var points = window.prompt('Please enter the achieved points of the participant:');
    points = parseInt(points, 10);
    if ((/[^0-9\s\-\']/gi.test(points)) || (points == ''))
    {
        alert ('You must enter a valid number! ');
        return;
    }

    participant.push({name: name, points: points});

    createChart();
};

function createChart ()
    {
        var i = 0;
        var len = participant.length;
        var bar = null;

        var container = document.getElementById('chart');
        container.innerHTML='';

        while (i < len)
        {

            bar = document.createElement('div');
            bar.style.width = barWidth + 'px';
            bar.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();
            bar.style.float = 'left';
            bar.style.marginRight = '10px';

            bar.style.height = ((participant[i].points / maxPoints) * 200) + 'px';
            bar.style.marginTop = 200 - parseInt(bar.style.height) + 'px';
            percent = ((participant[i].points / maxPoints) * 100) + '%';    
            bar.innerHTML = ['<p style="margin-top: ' + (parseInt(bar.style.height) - 17) + 'px">', percent, '<br />', participant[i].name, '</p>'].join('');

            container.appendChild(bar);

            i = i + 1;
        }
    };

function getRandomColor () {
    return ['rgb(', Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), ', ', Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), ', ', Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), ')'].join('');
 };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <label><input size="5" onkeyup="setMaxPoints()" /> Set Max Points</label><br /><br />
    <button onclick="gatherData()">Add Participant</button>
    <h4>Chart</h4>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kentas, here is my entire version of your code with the addition of an input box to get maxPoints:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>examAnalysis</title>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
div p
{ 
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var participant = [];
var maxPoints = 200;
var barWidth = 20;

window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value = maxPoints;
}

function setMaxPoints()
{
    maxPoints = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
}

function gatherData()
{
    var name = window.prompt('Please enter the name of the participant:');
    name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if ((/[^A-Z\s\-\']/gi.test(name)) || (name == '') || (name == 'undefined'))
    {
        alert ('You must enter a valid name! ');
        return;
    }

    var points = window.prompt('Please enter the achieved points of the participant:');
    points = parseInt(points, 10);
    if ((/[^0-9\s\-\']/gi.test(points)) || (points == ''))
    {
        alert ('You must enter a valid number! ');
        return;
    }

    participant.push({name: name, points: points});

    createChart();
};

function createChart ()
{
    var i = 0;
    var len = participant.length;
    var bar = null;

    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
    container.innerHTML='';

    while (i < len)
    {

        bar = document.createElement('div');
        bar.style.width = barWidth + 'px';
        bar.style.marginBottom = '5px';
        bar.style.backgroundColor = getRandomColor();

        bar.style.height = ((participant[i].points / maxPoints) * 200) + 'px';
        bar.style.marginTop = 200 - parseInt(bar.style.height) + 'px';
        percent = ((participant[i].points / maxPoints) * 100) + '%';

        bar.innerHTML = ['<p style="margin-top: ' + (parseInt(bar.style.height) - 17) + 'px">',  percent, '<br />', participant[i].name, '</p>'].join('');

        container.appendChild(bar);

        i = i + 1;
    }
};

function getRandomColor ()
{
    return ['rgb(', Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), ', ', Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), ', ', Math.floor(Math.random() * 255), ')'].join('');
};
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <label><input size="5" onkeyup="setMaxPoints()" /> Set Max Points</label><br /><br />
    <button onclick="gatherData()">Add Participant</button>
    <h4>Chart</h4>
    <div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The difference is the 2 functions I gave you.  They didn't work when they were all on 1 line like that.

Comment: A simple ';' between the two functions would have fixed it.  But like I said, trying to paste code in a comment gets messy.

Comment: Play with it...  I think you will agree that the input box is a better way to go than adding yet another popup prompt.

Comment: one last thing now..want to add the validation that the number im adding as achieved points can't be higher then the number i entered for maximum points..any easy way to do this? otherwise i just skip that

Comment: yes i agree this looks way better 3 pop ups is too much!

Comment: Try something like this:

Comment: if ((/[^0-9\s\-\']/gi.test(points)) || (points == '') || points > maxPoints)

Comment: Then change the alert to:

Comment: alert ('You must enter a valid number less than Max Points! ');

Comment: Here i asked a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757154/creating-slidingpuzzle-in-javascript maybe you can take a look at it and let me know if you need anymore information